# VxWorks Bootloader configuration

Tags: configuration, bootloader, vxworks

Motorola's embedded computer on card, MVME5500, according to jumper J8 position boots:

- MOTLoad   or  VxWorks loader.
  When boots MOTLoad, it can be seen two Ethernet NIC's ( Gigabit and 100/10 Mbit ) and one serial port.
  When boots VxWorks loader can be seen only Gigabit port and one serial.
  Can somebody help me in configuration of VxWorks loader ?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: Have you checked the target.ref or .nr file in the BSP directory? It might provides some information about what is supported for the boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the VxWorks loader doesn't have support the second NIC. Older board, so not sure what version your working with?

If there's driver available you could rebuild the loader with the additional driver and flash the new loader on the board.

Though it begs the question; why? Typically the loader is used to TFTP your custom kernel onto the board, and it's configured with whatever you want to use.

But as general rule, with VxWorks the default images have very little in them, it's assumed the dev process is an additive one.